# Insert picture to live camera

Tags: c++, opencv

I have question how I can insert a picture into a live camera ( in particular I have an face detection code, after detect face, I want it to circled my face and  display an image on top of the face). Any ideas will be appreciated.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// These are global variables
char face_cascade_name[] = "c:\\Program Files\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
char eyes_cascade_name[] = "c:\\Program Files\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;


// This is function detectAndDisplay()
// The input, or parameter, is a Mat object.
// It does not return a value, thus the return type "void".

void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame ) {
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );  // increase the image contrast
    //-- Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

    // For each face in the frame. faces[i] is a Rect, so it has a
    //     top-left corner (faces[i].x,faces[i].y)
    //     and dimensions faces[i].width x faces[i].height
    for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ ) {
        Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width/2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height/2 );

        ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width/2, faces[i].height/2), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 )

        Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );  // image of the face



    }
}


int main( void ) {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat frame;
    int frameCount;
    int fr=1,i=1;
      char name[20],s[20];
      Mat image;
      while(fr<=751)
      {
      sprintf(name,"Hello.jpg",i);

      image = imread(name,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

      if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
      {
      cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
      return -1;
      }
      sprintf(s,"pic/img%u.jpg",i);
      imwrite(s,image);
      fr++;
      i++;
      }
    namedWindow("Faces",CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

    // 1. Load the cascades
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ) {
        printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){
        printf("--(!)Error loading eyes cascade\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // 2. Read the video stream
    if (!cap.isOpened() ) {
        printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n");
        return -1;
    }


    for (frameCount = 0; frameCount < 1000000000; frameCount++) {

        cap >> frame;
        detectAndDisplay( frame );
        image.copyTo( frame );
        namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
        imshow( "Display window", image );
        imshow( "Faces",frame );
        int c = waitKey(10);
        if ((char)c == 27 ) {   // if the "Escape" key is pressed
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Post some code. If you have already a face detection code working, it should be fairly easy to display an image on top of the detected face.

Comment: This is my code so far, i have copy an image and paste it in the frame but it just cover all my frame https://bugs.vn/6015

Comment: Please, see my answer. It should be able to get you started. If it does not, maybe I can further improve it?

Comment: ok, I got your ans and it's useful. Can you help me to put text ( which is scanned from a file ) and put it on scren so it looks like I'm thinking. Thank you

Comment: To add text on screen, use [`putText`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576). I have updated my code snippet with this function. I think I answered your question so, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace pixels inside bounding rect with pixels of your image in loop or you can use ecopyTo function to copy your image inside part of your frame. Before that use resize function to fit an image to bounding box.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't know how put it in a specific region in my live camera, it's just cover all the frame. So far this is what I have https://bugs.vn/6015

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet of code shows you how to draw an image with **transparency** on top of another image. For this sample, I used two images:

- a [picture of a face](http://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/phil_Fak_II/Psychologie/Psy_II/beautycheck/english/durchschnittsgesichter/m(01-32)_gr.jpg) (*jpg* format)
- a [picture of a mustache](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/clubpenguin/images/8/86/CurlyMustache.png/revision/latest?cb=20130116174648) with **transparency** (*png* format)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat face;
    face = imread("face.jpg", 1); // the face we want to apply an image on. This can of course be replaced by a camera's frame.

    Mat mustache;
    mustache = imread("CurlyMustache.png", IMREAD_UNCHANGED); // the image we will apply on top of the face. IMREAD_UNCHANGED allows to load an image with its transparency channel.

    Size size = Size(118, 50);
    resize(mustache, mustache, size, 0.0,0.0, INTER_AREA); // resize the mustache to the wanted size. INTER_AREA interpolation gives good results.

    Point2i draw_position(160, 275); // the position where to draw the mustache

    // blend the mustache with the face
    for (int y = 0; y < mustache.rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mustache.cols; ++x)
        {
            cv::Vec4b & pixel = mustache.at<cv::Vec4b>(y, x); // mustache's pixel
            cv::Vec3b & pixel_dst = face.at<cv::Vec3b>(y + draw_position.y - size.height / 2, x + draw_position.x - size.width / 2); // destination image's (face) pixel

            pixel_dst = (pixel[3] / 255.0f) * Vec3b(pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]) + (1 - pixel[3] / 255.0f) * pixel_dst; // we blend the two pixels according to the transparency of the mustache's pixel.
        }
    }

    putText(face, "your text here", Point(draw_position.x - 20, draw_position.y - 50), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 2); // adds text on screen

    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Image", face);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: man's face with a mustache]

This solution is *not very efficient* (as we have to loop over all the pixels of the mustache's image) but as **OpenCV** doesn't mix up too well with *transparency*, I think it's a decent one. Hope it helps!